# Is there any option to display the File attachement data in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

When ever the CSV file is uploaded. Is there option to read the CSV and display the result in powerapps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think currently there is no way to do this directly in powerapp. You should use a Flow

Comment: Do we have any reference for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to read the contents of non-binary files in PowerApps. You can view images, hear audio, view PDF's, and display JSON payloads from API calls, but I do not know of a way to access plain text files such as .txt or .csv.

- You could display the data if user cuts-and-pastes the .csv content ([ref.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foGaOrBzVLc)).
- You *could* send the .csv to Power Automate, parse it and return it as JSON to display for the user. ([ref.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/import-csv/m-p/458786/highlight/true#M52))